# Inclusion of multiplier algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$, i.e there exists an inclusion map $\phi\colon B \rightarrow A$, can we conclude that there exists a $*$-homomorphism beween the multiplier algebras $\bar{\phi} \colon M(B)\rightarrow M(A)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $B$ sits inside $A$ non-degenerately. See [Prop. 2.1, Hilbert C*-Modules: A Toolkit for Operator Algebraists].

More precisely: If $(e_i)$ is an approximate unit for $B$ one may define 
$$
\bar \phi(x)\big (\phi(e_i)a \big) = \phi(xe_i)a \qquad ( x \in M(B), a \in A).
$$

Add: If $\phi \colon A \to B$ is any **surjective** $*$-hom. you also have an extension to the multiplier algebras.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't see what you are doing here. Are you taking limits over $i$? It seems like you are saying that an approximate unit of $B$ is also an approximate unit for $A$? That's not usually the case. And I don't see the relation with Lance's argument, where $B$ is an ideal and one obtains a map $A\to M(B)$.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that $(e_i)$ is an approximate unit for $B$ and by assumption $(\phi(e_i))$ is an approximate unit for $A$. That means that the map $B \hookrightarrow A \hookrightarrow M(A)$ is non-degenerate. Then, if you want to apply the result in Lance's book, note that $B$ is an ideal in $M(B)$ and hence you can extend the above mentioned map to a $*$-hom. $M(B) \to M(A)$.

Comment: I see. That's quite a requirement; not sure how often it happens.

Comment: I cannot really quantify it. However in classification, where I come from, it quite common that $*$-homomorphisms are lifts of Cu-morphisms, where you have control of the "rank" and the image of strictly positive elements.